Fourier transform of Light impulse
A function in the time domain and the frequency domain has inverse relationship in standard deviation. So the less standard deviation the function has in time domain the more spread out in the frequency domain. But lets take Energy and the time variable so if a function that represents a light impulse say a wave function. It has very small standard deviation in time domain and large standard deviation in frequency domain this means that the energy of this light impulse is every less right? Is it possible to make a light impulse such that it is perfectly balanced in both time and frequency domain like the gaussian distribution? If the standard deviation of the wave function of the red light is made to spread in time domain will the impulse become blue or violent means has higher frequency?

What you mean by "perfectly balanced in both time and frequency domain" ? Like having monochromatic ultra-short laser pulse ? No, it's not possible due to the limiting uncertainty principle $\Delta \omega \Delta \tau \ge 2 \pi$.

I meant that the fourier transform of the wave function of the light pulse in time domain would still be equal in frequency domain. The function is conserved. Like guassian distribution. Is it possible for a wave function (practically) is same both in time and frequency domain. Also if the red light's periodicity reduces will it become a light with higher frequency?

I find it quite hard to understand what you mean by "same functions" in time and frequency domain. Having same shape ? You can change shape by re-scaling $x$ domain or applying different scale transformations like $log(x)$ etc. So I doubt that equating shapes in different domains means something at all.

Exactly I was talking about shape sir well if you put it that way. As you know that the fourier transform of the guassian distribution is the guassian distribution itself. I was asking that is it possible to have a wave function in practice same as guassian? I mean without shrinking or spreading in time or frequency domain sir.

You mean is it possible to have such signal which is very short in time domain, and when converted into frequency domain - remains short pulse too (distributed over very narrow window of frequencies (peak) instead of spreaded over continuous spectrum? If so then I have answered to you already in the first comment - read it again. It's not possible due to uncertainty principle. Edge cases is that monochromatic (single-frequency) signal must be unbounded in time and single-period short pulses are distributed over continuous wide spectrum.
